# RTL TextField in Jasper iReport

Tags: jasper-reports

How can I rtl a textfield in *iReport*?

When English and Arabic combine, It screws up!

for example, you write "hi سلام", but it prints "سلام hi".

I searched all the internet, but nothing found.

Comment: You'll need to be more precise than "It screws up" for anyone to be able to help. In general it's well supported.

Comment: for example you write "hi سلام" , but it prints "سلام hi"

Comment: Do you get identical results for a TextField vs a StaticText element? They ought to be the same... but perhaps they are different. Start by confirming this.

Comment: I think there may be an issue. I see this old unresolved question. But to get a good answer I think you'll need to post a functioning report for others to immediately observe the problem and see exactly when it occurs: http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/537690/showing-persian-text-right-order

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's not static text, I fill textfield of jasper-reports by JavaBean. what does functioning report mean?